# Google Spreadsheet. Retrieve only one cell from ImportData-result

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-docs

I have this function:

```
=ImportData("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=7&c=2013&d=0&e=7&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv")
```

...which returns how a given stock was doing on a given date. The function returns a csv that looks like this:

```
Date      Open  High    Low    Close    Volume    Adj Close
1/7/2013  522   529.3   515.2  523.9    17291300  514.05
```

I.E: 2 rows and 7 columns is pasted in the cell I have the function in.

I am only interested in the value written in the Close-column. So is there a way to filter out this value so that "523.9" is all I would receive from the function written above?

Would be great if this is possible without storing the full table somewhere else first, but any solution is better than no solution of course. This is for Google Spreadsheet but perhaps its the same solution as in Excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this formula in your Google spreadsheet:

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("AAPL","price","2013-01-07"),2,2)
```

Or you can use your original ImportData method with the Index function.

```
=INDEX(ImportData("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=7&c=2013&d=0&e=7&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv"),2,5)
```

Each method will output the Close price only.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can only use the latter one though as GoogleFinance doesnt support as many markets.